# Electron Desktop app not able to set Chose Default apps by protocol for window 10 and etc

Tags: javascript, electron, geolocation, desktop-application, device

**Details and Steps**

I am not able to set Chose Default apps by protocol for our electron desktop app but this coming in APP & Future section .

Mean When I am running my installed app then that app coming my computer in **setting->APP** & Future but not in **Setting->Default Apps->Chose Default apps by protocol section** .

[image]

[image]

**I am using electron js for our desktop app.**

```
if (require("electron-squirrel-startup")) {
    app.quit();
} // NEW!

if (isDev && process.platform === "win32") {
  // Set the path of electron.exe and your app.
  console.log(process.execPath, [path.resolve(process.argv[1])]);
  app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient("call", process.execPath, [
    path.resolve(process.argv[1]),
  ]);
  app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient("aaa", process.execPath, [
    path.resolve(process.argv[1]),
  ]);
} else {
  app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient("call");
  app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient("aaa");

}

logEverywhere("app.makeSingleInstance# " + deeplinkingUrl);
```

So please let me reason or step are required for this changes but its also not coming "ups access point" as per browser with Customer service